# Browser display text but text is not in the HTML code

Tags: html

I need to capture the text inside an textarea element using Selenium. It means that to capture information I have to ask for the attributes inside an HTML element.

Please, look at the picture

[image]

The problem is at the `<textarea>` element besides the "Codigo Servicio" label. The text "VPF987654321" is clearly present in the textarea element, but this element shows no text (look at the highlighted code in the inspector). I search for the text in the inspector and nothing appears (0 of 0).

This is a webpage from a ticketing system that I do not administer.

- How it can be?
- How can I get the text?

Comment: Using `element.value`. To check how this works internally, you need to enable seeing the shadow DOM inside the element inspector.

Comment: Thank you. I am gonna to investigate about this shadow DOM feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content of the `<textarea>` is set with JavaScript not on HTML directly.

```js
document.getElementById('test').value = 'Hello StackOverflow (on JavaScript)';
```

```html
<textarea id="test"></textarea>
<textarea>Hello StackOverflow (on HTML)</textarea>
```

To get the value from `<textbox>` element you can use nearly the same JavaScript code:

```
 document.getElementById("id").value

 // or in your case

 document.getElementById("arid_WIN_3_536870915").value
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to capture the text with document.getElementById("id").value.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to get the value of the textarea at it's current state you could use javascript, like this:

```html
 <html>
                  <head>
                    <title>test</title>
                  </head>
                  <body>
                    <textarea onkeyup="getcurrenttext()" id='arid_WIN_3_536870915'>
                    </textarea>
                    <div id='result'></div>
                    <script>
                    function getcurrenttext() 
                    {
                        // Value of textarea at this very moment
                        var textareatext = document.getElementById('arid_WIN_3_536870915').value;
                        // The current text in the textarea should be shown in the console
                        console.log(textareatext)
                        // And also in a div for example purpose
                        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = textareatext;
                     }
                    </script>
                  </body>
                </html>
```